# Stuck on database procedure. Trying to display information in ASP.NET with an SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm having trouble having a query display on a webpage based on ASP.NET Forms.

I am trying to pull up information via student ID primary key, but it's not working. I cant find it anywhere in my textbooks or course videos.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetStudent
    @ StudentID int NOT NULL,
AS
BEGIN
  IF (@StudentID IS NOT NULL)
   SELECT * 
    FROM StudentDetail
     WHERE
      StudentID= @StudentID
END;
```

ERRORS:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetStudent, Line 2
> [Batch Start Line 0] Incorrect syntax near 'int'.
>
> Msg 137, Level 15,
> State 2, Procedure GetStudent, Line 5 [Batch Start Line 0] Must
> declare the scalar variable "@StudentID".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2,
> Procedure GetStudent, Line 9 [Batch Start Line 0] Must declare the
> scalar variable "@StudentID".

Comment: `@ StudentID` should be `@StudentID` without any spaces. That's why it's telling you it hasn't heard of any variable called `@StudentID` - it didn't understand what you wrote when you put it with the space, so it thinks you didn't define that variable.

Comment: Is your @ StudentID a typo, is this space wrong? Also your comma after NOT NULL is not valid

Comment: Problem has been rectified, thank you all very much.

Comment: Shame on whoever down-voted this question.  It was valid, well-written, and more complete than a lot of questions we see here.  I don't know about anyone else, but I've stared for **hours** at code like this wondering "why the ^#%*@# won't this work?!?", only to have someone spot the error in 7 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetStudent
    @StudentID int
AS
BEGIN
  IF (@StudentID IS NOT NULL)
   SELECT * 
    FROM StudentDetail
     WHERE
      StudentID= @StudentID
      ENd
```

Comment: One other thing, what is this specific type of Query called, i need to make 2 more, one for delete and one for update, so im hoping to research the commands.

Comment: This is simple select query (DML). In store proc you can write Delete and update as well. You can search merge syntax In which update and delete both are allowed in single query.